# R formula: how to constrain calculations to two groups using formula?

Tags: r

I want to build post-hoc testing for log-rank test, that compare individual groups to each other:

```
library(survival)
survdiff(DV ~ IV, data=mydf)
```

Is there any way to do something like this (e.g. to compare group 2 with group 7):

```
survdiff(DV ~ I(if(as.numeric(IV) == 2) {1} else {if(as.numeric(IV) == 7) {2} else {NA}} ), data=mydf )
```

---

I know that I can filter out not needed rows from `mydf` and the `Surv` object `DV`

```
df2vs7<-mydf[as.numeric(mydf$IV)==2 | as.numeric(mydf$IV)==7,]
DV2vs7<-DV[as.numeric(mydf$IV)==2 | as.numeric(mydf$IV)==7,]
```

But I think it is highly inefficient; the computer would need to store each separate data objects for each combination of compared groups.

Comment: Disagree with "highly inefficient" part.

Comment: @zx8754 Why? AFAIK, it would require roughly (n-1) times the memory the original mydf needs. R cannot subset rows cheaply (i.e. by reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

`survdiff(DV ~ IV, data=mydf[ as.numeric(mydf$IV) %in% c(2,7),] )`

Comment: Well, it isn't technically the answer for my question (it doesn't change the formula), but it definitely solves my problem. You should also do the same for the `DV` object as well (it cannot be part of the dataframe, because it is of type `Surv`)

Comment: Are `DV` and `I` variables from the same `mydf` dataframe?

Comment: _Actually it is `IV` not `I` (typo)_. Yes, they are from the same dataset, but `DV` is of type `Surv`.

Comment: As far as I know, when you subset a dataframe, you exclude rows for every column, so `DV` and `IV` is subsetted with my solution.

Comment: Yes. And I didn't know, that Surv can be part of a dataframe! I thought only `factor` and `vector` types could be!

Comment: So, this is the answer? If it was helpful please consider upvoting and/or accepting as an answer.

Comment: Its difficult to decide which of those two almost identical answers is better. I vote for you, only because you were first.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `subset` argument to `survdiff` inside a (nested) loop. You might have to tweak the loops to avoid off-by-one errors, but you get the idea.

```
l <- list()
n <- <no. of groups>
mydf$IV <- as.numeric(mydf$IV)
for(i in seq_len(n - 1))
{
    for(j in seq(i + 1, to=n, by=1))
    {
        l <- c(l, survdiff(DV ~ factor(IV), mydf, subset=IV %in% c(i, j)))
    }
}
```

Comment: Someone smarter than me could probably rewrite that using `*apply`.

Comment: The version pasted in a separate answer is a `plyr`ed and overhauled version of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this is a copy&paste solution. Suppose we have `df` a `dataframe` object, where we have `IV` categorical variable with `length(levels(df$IV))` levels, and the `DF` object of type `Surv` and we want to perform pairwise log-rank tests between each pair of groups

```
library(gregmisc)
levels<-sort(unique(as.numeric((mydf$IV))))
groups<-combinations(length(levels),2,levels)
#or if we assume that levels produced by as.numeric(mydf$IV) are in sequence 1:n, we can use more efficient:
#groups<-combinations(length(levels(df$IV)),2)
library(plyr)
alply(groups, 1, 
    function(pair) {
        survdiff(DV ~ factor(IV), mydf, subset=IV %in% c(pair[[1]], pair[[2]]))
    }
)
```

The last expression returns the results